# Redux- Form: Unable to Dispatch Action on Submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form in my React / Redux application, and I'm trying to figure out how to dispatch an action on submit.

I have been able to trigger the handleSubmit function, and the submit function that I pass to it is executed, but the 'submitFormValues' action is not called.

I've tried using mapDispatchToProps and connect(), but that doesn't work either.

The Redux-Form actions execute (START_SUBMIT, STOP_SUBMIT, SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEEDED), but my own action creator is never executed.

Here's the form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import {submitFormValues} from "../../../actions/BasicFormActions";


function submit(values) {
    //Can log the values to the console, but submitFormValues actionCreator does not appear to be dispatched.
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(submitFormValues(values))} )
}

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: {touched, error} }) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
    </div>
)

const BasicForm = (props) => {
    const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
            <Field name="firstName" type="text" component={renderField} label="First Name"/>
            <Field name="lastName" type="text" component={renderField} label="Last Name"/>
            {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
            <div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
                <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}



export default reduxForm({
    form: "basicForm",
    submit
})(BasicForm)
```

Here's the action Creator (uses Thunk). I'm able to dispatch these actions successfully, just not from the form.

```
 export const submitFormValues = (values) => (dispatch) =>
        getData("submitApproveForm", values).then(response => {
            dispatch(formSubmissionError(response))
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });

const formSubmissionError = (response) =>
    ({
        type: types.FORM_SUBMISSION_ERROR,
        basicFormResponse: { ...response}
    });


export const getData = (apiName, args) =>
    fetch(settings.basePath + getUrl(apiName, args))
        .then(response =>
    response.json()
    ).catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

Finally my reducer:

```
import * as types from "../actions/ActionsTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

const basicFormReducer = (state = initialState.basicFormResponse, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FORM_SUBMISSION_ERROR:
            return {...state, "errors": action.basicFormResponse}; // returns a new state
        case types.FORM_SUBMISSION_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, "successes": action.basicFormResponse}; // returns a new state
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default basicFormReducer;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like you has wrong use of Promise. You probably need to `return new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(values) } ).then(submitFormValues)`

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I've tried both with and without a promise in the submit function. The problem seems to be that the dispatch() function is not available. I think it has something to do with the way reduxForm wraps the component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Redux Form does not dispatch anything in the `onSubmit` callback. This is because we make no assumptions regarding how you would like to deal with your form submissions.

You can, however, [use the `dispatch` argument](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-onsubmit-function-optional-) and... dispatch your action!

```
function submit(values, dispatch) {
    return dispatch(submitFormValues(values));
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thanks @gustavohenke!

Comment: doesn't work for me I get "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function"

Comment: How can I populate the form with errors if using the dispatch method? The action itself doesn't throw any errors obviously...

Comment: @zeraien handle your submission logic  in your handleSubmit function and use a Promise and reject it or throw a SubmissionError object if there are any errors